# Generate new workbooks based on column value from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA. Basically I need a code that generates a new workbook for each specific column value in multiple sheets. The key in each sheet is the column Group.

In total there are 6 sheets in the original file with the following columns. 
**Sheet General Data**

Location    Project Project Manager Status Group

**Sheet Costs**

Location    Group   Project Costs

**Sheet Costs Last month**

Location    Group   Project Costs last month

**Sheet issues**

Location    Project Project Manager Issues Group

Additionally there are two other sheets in the wb that need to be transferred as well but kept as they are. ("Overview" and "Summary").
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. As a reminder, this is not a code writing website. We are here to help with any issues you have with your code but not to actually write the code for you

Comment: Hi, I cannot figure out the steps to do it simple.  Anyone, with a proposal?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a draft, but it autofilters also  the sheets "Summary" and "Overview". Therefore they are copied twice into the destination wb.

Sub SplitWB()
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, team
For Each team In getTeams
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add ' create a wb for each team with same # of sheets

    Do Until wb.Worksheets.Count >= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        wb.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Loop

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Overview" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        With ws.UsedRange
            .AutoFilter 1, team ' filter to copy only the team's rows
            .Copy wb.Sheets(ws.Index).Range("A1")
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        End If
        wb.Sheets(ws.Index).Name = ws.Name


    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        wb.SaveAs "Project Budget Tracking " & team & ".xlsx"

```
    wb.Close False
Next
```

Cleanup:
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function getTeams() ' gets the unique team names using a dictionary
    Dim cel As Range, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Len(Trim(cel.Value2)) > 0 Then dict(cel.Value2) = 0
        Next
    End With
    getTeams = dict.Keys
End Function